# Good way to handle global commands with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, events, redux

I've got a React/Redux application where I have a number of global commands that can be called in various ways - via context menu, via shortcut, or by clicking on a button.

These commands are then handled in the place relevant to the command (for example if the command is "save", it is handled by the text editor component).

So far I've done this in a convoluted way:

- I dispatch a "COMMAND_EXEC" action like so: `{ type: "COMMAND_EXEC", name: "save_note" }`, which in the reducer populates a state property "current_command"
- Then in the component I map this current_command state property to a prop
- Finally in `componentWillReceiveProps`, I check if there's a "current_command" property and handle it.
- Once it has been handled I clear the command with a different Redux action "COMMAND_CLEAR"

It kind of works but it's over complicated and I suspect it might cause issue as there's more and more components and commands. And I guess I'm using Redux actions as events, which is probably not a good idea.

So I'm wondering if there a more proper way to handle these kind of events in Redux?

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depend on what these commands are expected to do:

1. Are these commands doing UI updates which are very tightly dependant on state of the component?
2. Are these commands making an api call / navigating to a different route etc?

*Case (2)*

The View (React Component) should not be the ideal place to execute this command.  Rather, you should execute the command as an action.  The text editor component should dispatch an action "save" which is handled by redux.  Any other XYZ component can also call the same action "save".  If the action requires the current state of text-component, you should maintain this state in a reducer.

*Case (1) -- UI Updates*

It is not a very good idea to keep UI state in a reducer unless required. But at times, you would need to do it. See the following example:

You have a switch which turns "off" and "on", the `Switch` Component should be the ideal place to keep its own `state.isOn`. When updated, it would let its parent know by `this.props.onUpdate`.

Now, what if an external action wants to flip the switch?  The best way to do that would be to lift the `state` of `Switch` Component up to a Parent level and let the parent handle everything for the Switch Component.

Read: [Lifting State Up - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Similarly, you would "lift the state" for your UI Component to reducer and allow actions to modify the state of your redux store. The View components would simply listen to store updates and re-render accordingly.

---

What you are supposedly doing is:

- The React Component manages its own state
- Its state can also be changed by an external command to which it listens using `componentWillReceiveProps`

which will make the application messy and difficult to manage.

---

*The possible solution:*

- Actions should be the place where global commands are actually executed
- Reducers should be the place to keep application state required to execute these global commands
- These global actions could be dispatched from anywhere in the application
- The result of these global actions would again be stored in a reducer which the UI Components would listen to and update themselves.